# How do you test route constraints using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, constraints

Given a couple of cities in the DB:

```
City.first.attributes => {:id => 1, :name => 'nyc'}
City.last.attributes =>  {:id => 2, :name => 'boston'}
```

And a route like:

```
match '/:city/*dest' => 'cities#do_something', :constraints => {:city => /#{City.all.map{|c| c.name}.join('|'}/}
```

(so the constraints should evaluate to: /nyc|boston/)

And a spec:

```
it "recognizes and generates a route for city specific paths" do
  { :put => '/bad-city/some/path' }.should route_to({:controller => "cities", :action => "do_something", :dest => 'some/path', :city => 'bad-city'})
end
```

I would expect a failure. But it passes.

Likewise:

```
it "doesn't route bad city names" do
  { :put => '/some-bad-city/some/path' }.should_not be_routable
end
```

Here I expect it to pass, but it fails.

It seems the constraint is being ignored in the specs, since the matching cities have the same behavior as the bad ones.

Is this a known issue, or am I missing something that I need to do?

Comment: Because this works in dev, but not test, I'm thinking the problem is that the constraint is evaluated at startup, and in the test DB there are no cities at that point. So the regex looks like //, and matches everything. But when I try to make it a Proc, or a class implementing #matches?(request) it never seems to get called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This approach works:
In routes.rb

```
match '/:city/*destination' => 'cities#myaction', :constraints => {:city => /#{City.all.map{|c|c.slug}.join('|')}/}
```

In the spec:

```
describe "routing" do
  before(:each) do
    @mock_city = mock_model(City, :id => 42, :slug => 'some-city')
    City.stub!(:find_by_slug => @mock_city, :all => [@mock_city])
    MyApp::Application.reload_routes!
  end

  it "recognizes and generates a route for city specific paths" do
    { :get => '/some-city/some/path' }.should route_to({:controller => "cities", :action => "myaction", :destination => 'some/path', :city => 'some-city'})
  end

  it "rejects city paths for cities that don't exist in the DB" do
    { :get => '/some-bad-city/some/path' }.should_not be_routable
  end
end
```

Lastly, I added an observer to reload routes whenever the cities table changes.

Comment: It's horrible to use a db find all in the routes.rb like that. In this case, the controller or a before_filter should validate the city.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify constraints, you must include the parameter to constrain:

```
match '/:city/*dest' => 'cities#do_something', :constraints => { :city => /nyc|boston|philly/ }
```

Comment: You know - in my trying to simplify the problem, I introduced a typo. Thanks for the catch.